# HTTP PATCH operation fails in IE 11, works in Chrome, Firefox

Tags: jquery, rest, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, azure-mobile-services

This is the snippet related to the PATCH operation from a [larger working sample](https://gist.github.com/mvark/7521891cffb39c2ead63)

```
function restPatch(food) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://example.azure-mobile.net/tables/food/' + food.id,
        type: 'PATCH',
        datatype: 'json',
        beforeSend: setHeader,
        data: food,
        success: function (data) {
            toastr.success('Edited ' + data.item);
        },
        error: function () { toastr.error('Operation failed! Please retry'); }
    });
}
```

I'm using jQuery 2.1.0. The PATCH operation reflects in the list of network calls within Firebug and Chrome Dev Tools and works correctly in Firefox and Chrome but the operation doesn't appear & there seems to be no request made while tracking the HTTP calls in Dev Tools in IE 11. When I tested the CRUD operations for the web service independently with the POSTMAN tool they all work fine.  Only the edit operation doesn't work on IE 11 desktop & mobile, the GET, POST, DELETE HTTP operations work fine. Am I doing something wrong? What can be done to make the PATCH operation work in IE 11?

[PATCH is the officially supported way for the Azure Mobile Services-based web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj677198.aspx) to update a record.

Update on 22/Dec: When I tested the sample on [IE Technical Preview remotely](https://remote.modern.ie/) on version 11.0.9878.0, the PATCH operation worked! On Win 8.1, IE 11.0.9600 the PATCH operation doesn't work.

Comment: @Cosmin I added my question - What can be done to make the PATCH operation work in IE 11?

Answer (score 3):

Simply put (see what I did there), you can't. There's nothing you can really put on your web page to make a browser use a HTTP verb if it doesn't support it.

That said, you can work around it:

```
function restPatch(food) {
    // Checks if IE v6-11
    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/at-cc-on-statement-javascript
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

    var ajaxType = 'PATCH';
    var ajaxData = food;

    if(isIE) {
        ajaxType = 'POST';
        ajaxData._isHttpPatch = true;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://example.azure-mobile.net/tables/food/' + food.id,
        type: ajaxType,
        datatype: 'json',
        beforeSend: setHeader,
        data: ajaxData,
        success: function (data) {
            toastr.success('Edited ' + data.item);
        },
        error: function () { toastr.error('Operation failed! Please retry'); }
    });
}
```

Then on the server-side, you would check if data._isHttpPatch is set = true, and if so, treat it as a PATCH request.

Of course, it depends whether you have request type overloading - i.e. if you have a REST service which has two methods for /tables/food/{id}, one which operates on a POST, one on a PATCH, and you need to code a fix for this, then you might decide it's easier to just always set this flag on the client.

This is effectively what a lot of frameworks do. If you take Laravel for example, it adds a hidden HTML input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="_patch" />
```

The only other thing to bear in mind is that HTTP PATCH shouldn't just take an object with, for example, only the updated properties set. It should take an object which describes the difference (think Git diff), or a JSON Merge Patch message (which has a Content-Type of 'application/merge-patch+json'); see http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/. This means you could have them all as POSTs and then use the Content-Type header, or some other unique identifier in the patch description to determine that it is indeed a patch rather than a replacement.

Sadly, otherwise, it's a case of waiting for the likes of IE11 to to be updated on your user's computers. Ho hum!